# Framer motion and exit property not working with InertiaJs

Tags: reactjs, inertiajs, framer-motion

I would like to know how can I use "exit" property with framer motion and InertiaJs / ReactJs please.

Currently I have two pages :

> profil.js

```
const { pathname } = window.location
...

<div>
    <motion.div className="flex flex-col" layoutId={`title-3`}
            initial={{opacity: 0}}
            animate={{
                y: [-20, 0],
                opacity: [0, 1]
            }}
            exit={{scale: 2}}
            key={{pathname}}
            transition={{duration: 0.2, ease: "easeOut", delay: 0.1}}
>
    <span>Profil</span>
    </motion.div>
</div>
```

> home.js

```
const { pathname } = window.location
...

<div>
    <motion.div className="flex flex-col" layoutId={`title-3`}
            initial={{opacity: 0}}
            animate={{
                y: [-20, 0],
                opacity: [0, 1]
            }}
            exit={{scale: 2}}
            key={{pathname}}
            transition={{duration: 0.2, ease: "easeOut", delay: 0.1}}
>
    <span>Home</span>
    </motion.div>
</div>
```

And I set AnimateSharedLayout on my App (app.js) :

```
import { AnimateSharedLayout } from 'framer-motion';

return render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <AnimateSharedLayout>
            <App {...props} />
        </AnimateSharedLayout>
    </Provider>, el
);
```

When I click on "home" or "profil" in the sidebar, I see the animate, but I don't see the exit animation.

I use InertiaJs and ReactJs.

Do you have an idea why I don't see the exit ?

Answer (score 0):

Once you click away from "home" or "profile", that element is removed from the  DOM right away, so it won't be there long enough to see the animation.

[Framer Motion Docs](https://www.framer.com/docs/examples/#exit-animations)

> By wrapping motion components with AnimatePresence, they gain the use of an exit property that can define either a set of values or a variant name to animate to before being removed.

Try wrapping your `<motion.div>`s with `<AnimatePresence>` like this:

```
const { pathname } = window.location
...

<div>
    <AnimatePresence>
    <motion.div className="flex flex-col" layoutId={`title-3`}
            initial={{opacity: 0}}
            animate={{
                y: [-20, 0],
                opacity: [0, 1]
            }}
            exit={{scale: 2}}
            key={{pathname}}
            transition={{duration: 0.2, ease: "easeOut", delay: 0.1}}
    >
    <span>Home</span>
    </motion.div>
    </AnimatePresence>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx @Andrew for your answer. I tried with AnimatePresence embed, but same thing...

Comment: Hmmm.... are `home` and `profile` inside a router?

Comment: I use InertiaJs

Comment: Your issue is probably related to that. When you change routes, the page you are coming from is unmounted before the animation can show. `AnimatePresence` can't help there because `AnimatePresence` is unmounted right away as well.

Comment: Do you have an idea, how can I wait before the unmounted to see the animation ?

Comment: exit animation is meant for same page animation

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial do you have an example with InertiaJs please ?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with inertia and react. The fix was very simple.
Just add transition property with a duration to the exit prop.

e.g. for your case it should look like

> 

```
<AnimatePresence>
<motion.div className="flex flex-col" layoutId={`title-3`}
        initial={{opacity: 0}}
        animate={{
            y: [-20, 0],
            opacity: [0, 1]
        }}
        exit={{scale: 2, transition:{duration:0.2}}}
        key={{pathname}}
        transition={{duration: 0.2, ease: "easeOut", delay: 0.1}}
>
<span>Home</span>
</motion.div>
</AnimatePresence>
```

The difference is with the exit prop